# Regex replacing part of link

Tags: python, regex, replace

I need to write a regex, that will traverse through my file and replace each :

`href='#!/api/API.`

with

`href='http://www.domain.com/API.` . I currently have this kind of code, that will be run from console :

```
def replace(file, pattern, substring):
    my_file = open(file)
    for line in my_file:
        my_file.write(line.replace(pattern, substring))
```

Will sending the given strings work in this case ?

Comment: Can't you just use the standard search/replace functionality in your editor?

Comment: Yes/no questions are no good fit for this site, because all the possible answers don't fulfill the minimum length requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to replace `#!/api` with `http://www.domain.com`?

You can just do:

```
line.replace('#!/api','http://www.domain.com')
```

No need for regex.

Comment: So that's a "yes", I guess :)

Comment: first I thought that the replace string will be more complicated, but it turns out it's not. thanks anyway